# How to format the birthdate to display DD/MM/YYYY in express.js

Tags: express

How to format the birthdate to display DD/MM/YYYY in express.js

```
if (lodash.has(userData, 'birthDate')) {
        let parsedDate = Date.parse(userData.birthDate);
        if (!isNaN(parsedDate)) {
            let bDate = new Date(userData.birthDate);
            enrichment.birthDate = bDate;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you can use moment npm for get any type of format

You can pass your birthdate in moment(YOUR_BIRTHDATE)

For more details you can refer:- https://momentjs.com/

```
var moment = require('moment');
console.log(moment().format("DD/MM/YYYY"));
```